# Reverse a domain name string

Tags: c++, strings, interview-questions

For an interview question, I was asked to do the following:

> Given a dot separated domain name, reverse the domain elements.

Here are a few input/output examples:

```
codereview.stackexchange.com -> com.stackexchange.codereview
foo.bar -> bar.foo
a.. -> ..a
```

This was my proposed solution. I really feel like there's probably a better way to do this (in place?).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string
reverse(const std::string &str)
{
    std::string rstr = str;
    std::reverse(rstr.begin(), rstr.end());
    int size = rstr.size();
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
    while (end != size + 1) {
        if (rstr[end] == '.' || end == size) {
            std::reverse(rstr.begin() + start, rstr.begin() + end);
            start = end + 1;
        }
        ++end;
    }
    return rstr;
}

int 
main()
{
    std::string examples[] = {
        "hello.world",
        "com.domain.something",
        "..a"
    };

    int size = sizeof(examples) / sizeof(examples[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        std::cout << examples[i] << " -> " << reverse(examples[i]) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As discusses with @holroy in his comments and [gist](https://gist.github.com/Loki-Astari/394661d4c5e36aa8cc02). Building objects dynamically is a much slower technique. Reversing the string in place using the double reverse technique (that you use) is the better solution.

Comment: If you are looking for a review of an interview question then you have accepted the wrong answer. The advice by hilroy is just wrong. The cost of memory allocation (as shown) is so expensive in comparison to a two pass reverse (unless your string are several Kbytes long) that it will always be slower. Janos answer is the correct one. As an interviewer the two pass solution is the conical correct answer.

Comment: I would also note: Hilroy's implementation may be twice as fast as yours. The implementation I provide (an optimized version of yours) is 3 times faster than his. Check the [gist](https://gist.github.com/Loki-Astari/394661d4c5e36aa8cc02) for timing info.

Comment: @LokiAstari This was my first time posting in this stack exchange network and I must say that it really feels like a real-life situation where programmers debate endlessly on whether A or B is the best solution. I'm guessing that upvotes are probably a better way to chose the right answer vs my personal judgement (as influenced as it might have been).

Comment: I've got no problem with you switching your accepted answer, but in most cases readability and understandable code is more worth than the optimization and rather specialized use case that Loki Astari advocates. In addition his timings differs from those benchmarks I've done, where my benchmarks indicates similar run times for his and mine solution. But your mileage may vary, and I'm not going to pursue this any more.

Comment: @Hilroy I agree that readability is the most important. And the version I posted is definitely the most readable and easy to understand (but your mileage may very). As for speed tests that's easy to verify just run the test on your system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks quite fine to me. Granted, you make several passes over the entire string, but that doesn't matter much, as the time complexity remains \$O(n)\$, space complexity constant, and this is easy to read and understand.

You could reduce the number of passes by using extra storage, in which you could *prepend* the reversed segments. But due to the extra storage, such algorithm would not be *better*, it would be *different*. Whether one solution is better than the other depends on external constraints not stated in the problem. Talking about this is important at an interview, more important than whatever solution you gave.

In terms of the implementation, the only thing I would change is convert the main while loop to a for loop. The reason is that the start and end variables are only used inside the loop body, and the for loop would help confining them into that scope, which is a good thing, reducing the *live time* of those variables, and preventing accidental uses outside the loop.

Answer (score 4):

**Main Suggestion**

I think it will be useful to have couple of overloaded functions, one for working with `const std::string`s and one for regular `std::string`s.

With a `const std::string`, pay the cost of making a copy, reversing the copy, and returning the copy.

With a `std::string`, you can avoid all the above costs. You make all modifications to the string in place.

```
std::string& reverse(std::string& str)
{
   // Don't pay the cost of making copies for regular strings.
   std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
   int size = str.size();
   int start = 0;
   int end = 0;
   while (end != size + 1) {
      if (str[end] == '.' || end == size) {
         std::reverse(str.begin() + start, str.begin() + end);
         start = end + 1;
      }
      ++end;
   }

   return str;
}

std::string reverse(std::string const& str)
{
   std::string copy = str;
   return reverse(copy);
}
```

Now, you can reverse regular `std::string`s as well as temporary `std::string`s, i.e. `const std::string`s, while paying the cost of making copies only for `const std::string`s.

```
int main()
{
    std::string examples[] = {
        "hello.world",
        "com.domain.something",
        "..a"
    };

    int size = sizeof(examples) / sizeof(examples[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        std::cout << examples[i] << " -> " << reverse(examples[i]) << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "abc.com" << " -> " << reverse("abc.com") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Use right type names**

Don't use `int` where other type names are more appropriate. You can use `auto` to avoid such issues. I would recommend replacing

```
int size = str.size();
int start = 0;
int end = 0;
```

with

```
auto size = str.size();
decltype(size) start = 0;
decltype(size) end = 0;
```

**Using `std::reverse` vs hand crafted function to reverse a string**

You can reverse a string or part of the string using `std::reverse` like you have in your code:

```
std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
```

and

```
std::reverse(str.begin() + start, str.begin() + end);
```

You can also reverse a string or part of the string using a hand crafted function:

```
void reverse_string(std::string& str, size_t start, size_t end)
{
   for ( --end; start <= end; ++start, --end )
   {
      char c = str[start];
      str[start] = str[end];
      str[end] = c;
   }
}
```

and use it as:

```
reverse_string(str, 0, str.size());
```

and

```
reverse_string(str, start, end);
```

I noticed that the hand crafter version performs 50% faster than `std::reverse`.

Sample program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

void timeFunction(void (*fun)(int, std::string&), int N, std::string& str)
{
   clock_t start = std::clock();
   fun(N, str);
   clock_t end = std::clock();
   double secs = 1.0*(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
   std::cout << "Time taken: " << secs << std::endl;
}

void test_reverse_string_1(int N, std::string& str)
{
   for (int n = 0; n < N; ++n )
   {
      std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
   }
}

void reverse_string(std::string& str, size_t start, size_t end)
{
   for ( --end; start <= end; ++start, --end )
   {
      char c = str[start];
      str[start] = str[end];
      str[end] = c;
   }
}

void test_reverse_string_2(int N, std::string& str)
{
   for (int n = 0; n < N; ++n )
   {
      reverse_string(str, 0, str.size());
   }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   int N = atoi(argv[1]);
   std::string str = argv[2];
   timeFunction(test_reverse_string_1, N, str);
   timeFunction(test_reverse_string_2, N, str);
   return 0;
}
```

Command to build (under Linux, using g++ 4.8.4) :

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++11     socc.cc   -o socc
```

Execution and ouput:

```
>> ./socc 1000000 "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."

Time taken: 0.484501
Time taken: 0.297132

>> ./socc 4000000 "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."

Time taken: 1.92211
Time taken: 1.02913
```

**Standard Disclaimer**

Your mileage may vary depending on your compiler and run time environment.

Answer (score 3):

**Reference vs Value**

```
std::string
reverse(const std::string &str)
{
    std::string rstr = str;
```

If you wish for you algorithm to make a copy and you are not using the original string, pass by value.  Your function also is not a plain reverse, so give it an appropriate name.

**Prefer C++-style declarations** (`const std::string& str`)

References/pointers relate more to the type than the expressions/grammar.

**Ensure all dependencies are included**

```
    std::reverse(rstr.begin(), rstr.end());
```

Missing `<algorithm>`.

**Prefer `for` over `while` when using loop variables**

```
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
    while (end != size + 1) {
        // ...
        ++end;
    }
```

The logic for the loop is up front.

**Prefer initializing loop variables in the `for` initialization when not used out of the loop**

**Avoid magic constants**

```
        if (rstr[end] == '.' || end == size) {
```

Magic/Literal constants can sometimes be overlooked.  Use symbolic constants, as they provide semantic context when reading.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try to avoid explicit loops, and playing around with indices yourself. Instead, we can let the standard library do most of the work for us. Indeed, let us use a stringstream to parse the input string (the delimiter is a dot). After the string has been split into parts, we reverse its elements, and write the contents to a new string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    const std::string s = "codereview.stackexchange.com";
    std::istringstream iss(s);

    std::vector<std::string> parts;
    for (std::string token; std::getline(iss, token, '.'); )
        parts.emplace_back(token);

    std::ostringstream oss;
    std::reverse(parts.begin(), parts.end());
    std::copy(parts.begin(), parts.end() - 1, std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(oss, "."));
    oss << parts.back();

    std::cout << oss.str() << "\n";
}
```

It worth noticing that the above is not exactly correct, outputting on ".a" on "a.." (instead of the expected "..a"). This can also be handled, but I'll omit it to convey the idea.

Answer (score 1):

As you might understand from my original comments on your post, I don't agree with janos, that your solution is easy to read and understand. Here is the main issues I have with your solution:

- I find it confusing to reverse the entire string, and then to undo the first reverse for each domains one by one. Timewise this results in two traversals of the original string: One for the initial reversal, and one by the while loop reversing it back again
- You kind of hide the `std::reverse` with your choice of name for the function, and then when using it within the function you have to look twice to make sure you are not writing a recursive function. Nameing your main function, `reverse_domains`, would aleviate this, and also give a clearer indication on what your function actually does
- You also name the length variable for `size`, which is the same as the name of the function used to calculate it, `size()`. This complicates the logic a little bit, because you have to distinguish between doing the call of the function, or the use of the length variable
- Similarily using `str` and `rstr` is unneccessary confusing. It would look better to use `result` instead of `rstr` in my opinion.

On the bright side, your code is nicely indented, and you are pretty consistent with bracing style, and other stylistic elements. And it does what it is supposed to do!

### Alternate algorithm

In the comments I suggested to use split and join, which has been commented upon by another answer afterwards. In the answer by janos, it's suggested to keep as is, but here is a faster alternative where you only traverse the text once, whilst building the result string.

Code follows:

```
std::string reverse_domains(const std::string& source)
{
    std::string result;
    size_t source_length = source.size();
    size_t end = source_length;

    // Loop from end of string to reverse the domains
    for (int i = source_length; i >= 0; i--) {

        // If not domain divider, continue 
        if (source[i] != '.') {
            continue;
        }

        // Append the domain substring
        result.append(source, i+1, end - i);
        result += '.'; // Append divider
        end = i-1; // Set end point of next domain
    }

    // Copy the last bit of source string, if needed
    if ((end = result.size()) != source_length) {
        result.append(source, 0, source_length - end);
    }
    return result;
}
```

In this code I've also added a few comments to explain what is going on, which was missing in your original code. And I used a little longer, but more descriptive variable names. Note that this method has the same space complexity as yours, as it creates a string to be returned, but the time complexity has been halfed as it only traverses the string once.

#### Performance comparison

I did a simple comparison test at repl.it (see [complete code](https://repl.it/B6Xw/1)), running the reversal of a given list of domains (including your samples) 10 000 times, and taking the time. Your version clocked in at around 0.024 seconds, whilst mine clocked in at around 0.013 seconds. That is almost half the time of your code, or a 50 % improvement.

### Addendum on memory cost

It has been argued by LokiAstari that my solution is not the fastest one, which is a claim I haven't made, and that the cost of memory allocation is more important than traversal costs. When comparing mine versus the OP solution, the memory cost is almost identical as both solutions uses a `const std::string &` as input, and not a mutable string. And timings clearly indicate which solution is the faster.

If you change to a mutable string, and does an in-place edit, faster solutions does exist, where one is presented [here](https://gist.github.com/Loki-Astari/394661d4c5e36aa8cc02). This does use the double reversing method and in-place editing, but is even less readable and understandable than the OP version, from my point of view. This solution claims to be 3 times faster than my solution (half-heartedly transformed into an in-place edition).