# Time complexity of several methods of reversing a domain name string

Tags: c++, algorithm, strings, comparative-review, complexity

**Note**: I'm aware of [this existing post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/113030/reverse-a-domain-name-string) which is similar. However, it does not address all my questions sufficiently.

---

I have the following three functions, all of which do the same thing: reverse a domain name string.

```cpp
std::string reverse_domain(const std::string& s) {
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string segment;
    std::vector<std::string> breakList;

    while (std::getline(ss, segment, '.')) {
        breakList.push_back(segment);
    }

    std::string result;

    auto size = breakList.size();

    for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        result += breakList[i];

        if (i != size - 1) {
            result += ".";
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

```cpp
std::string reverse_domain2(const std::string& s) {
    std::string result;
    auto index = 0;

    for (const auto& c : s) {
        if (c == '.') {
            index = 0;
            result.insert(result.begin() + index, '.');
            continue;
        }

        result.insert(result.begin() + index, c);
        index++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

```cpp
std::string reverse_domain3(std::string& copy) {
    std::reverse(copy.begin(), copy.end());
    auto start = 0;

    auto size = copy.size();

    for (auto i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
        if (copy[i] != '.' && i != size) continue;

        std::reverse(copy.begin() + start, copy.begin() + i);
        start = i + 1;
    }

    return copy;
}
```

My question is, what is the time complexity of all of these?

My educated guesses are:

- For `reverse_domain`: \$O(n) + O(n^2) + ?\$. The reasoning behind this is that I assume the `getline` loop is \$O(n)\$, and I assume appending to a string is \$O(n)\$, hence why I assume the `for` loop is \$O(n^2)\$. The last remaining piece is actually creating the string stream, hence the `?` I have.
- For `reverse_domain_2`: \$O(n^2)\$. The reasoning behind this is that `insert` is linear time, and so the whole for loop would just be \$O(n^2)\$.
- For `reverse_domain_3`: \$O(n) + O(n^2)\$. The reasoning behind this is that reversal is linear time. And in the for loop, there's another reversal, hence \$O(n^2)\$. However, since its only reversing a piece of the string, I'm not too sure.

Are all these assumptions and time complexities correct?

I timed the performance of each of these methods on a multivariate plot, where the x axis is the length of the string, the y axis is the number of `"."` characters, and the z axis is the duration.

As you can see, `reverse_domain` is by far the slowest, and the other two are similar, with `reverse_domain_3` being the fastest. However, I'm not exactly too sure why this is. I'm also not sure how to (or if I should) express the time complexity in terms of just the string length, or the length as well as the number of `"."` characters?

Thanks for any explanation(s).

[image: plot]

Comment: Big-O notation represents _asymptotic complexity_, so we don't normally write "O(n) + O(n²)" like that.  As n gets larger, the linear term becomes insignificant compared to the quadratic term, so that becomes simply O(n²).

Comment: `reverse_domain2()`: What is the result of `result.begin() + index` immediately after `index = 0;`?

Answer (score 1):

## `reverse_domain()`

This one has the largest extra space requirements, due to us creating a vector holding copies of all the components.  It could be more efficient if the vector held string-view objects instead.

We could ensure that `result` doesn't need to reallocate if we reserve enough space - we know that it will be exactly the same size as the input string, because we're just rearranging the characters:

```
result.reserve(s.size())
```

We have a bug when we use `int i` to index the vector.  Its size is a `std::size_t`, which has a different signedness and range to `int`.  We can avoid the index variable altogether, though:

```
const char* sep = "";
for (const auto& component: std::views::reverse(breakList)) {
    result += sep;
    result += component;
    sep = ".";
}
```

Runtime should scale as O(n) - appending to a string that has enough capacity should be linear in the quantity being appended, and independent on the string's length (unlike `std::strcat()`, which needs to examine the whole string to find the end).

## `reverse_domain2()`

We don't need to force the caller to pass a `std::string` here - we could accept a `std::string_view` instead.

This function has the same problem of not reserving result capacity.

The type of `index` is deduced from `0` as `int`, but we need a `std::size_t` - it's better to be specific here.  Alternatively, and more simply, we can use an iterator into the result string (once we've made sure it won't need to reallocate):

```
auto it = result.begin();
```

The implementation of this one doesn't require any extra storage beyond what's needed for the result, but the `insert()` operation is costly because it involves moving the existing string data to make room.  As you state, that makes this version scale as O(n²).

## `reverse_domain3()`

This is problematic, because of the misleadingly-named argument `copy`, which is a reference.  We ought to accept `std::string` *by value* rather than by reference; if callers no longer need the original, they can use `std::move()` to make the copy cheaper.

Again, we use the wrong types for `start` and `size`, and for the loop iterator `i`.  All these should be `std::size_t`.

Instead of looping over each character, we can offload that to our library, using `std::find()` or `std::string::find()` to locate each `'.'` in the string.

The asymptotic complexity here is linear, O(n), because each character is affected exactly twice by `std::reverse()`.  And like `reverse_domain2`, we use no extra storage (and can re-use the caller's storage if the argument is move-constructed).